# How to add #toolbar=0 after src={pdf} in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to display a PDF in modal, with

```
import pdf from '../media/pdf/mypdf.pdf'

<iframe src={pdf} width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>
```

This works great.

But I also want to remove toolbar, so I have to add `#toolbar=0` at the end of the url

How should I do it, for some reason, I can't put the path directly into src attribute, I must use a variable, and I don't know how to append `#toolbar=0` on it ?

any idea ?

EDIT:

import mypdf from '../media/pdf/mypdf.pdf'

```
class HomeLayout extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                <main>
                    <div className="modal fade" id="fichePremian" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                            <div className="modal-content " >
                                <div className="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal-body">
                                    <iframe src={mypdf} width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main >
            </div>
        </div>
        )//return
    }

}

export default HomeLayout;
```

Comment: Have you tried assigning a React `ref` to the `iframe` element and then appending `#toolbar=0` to the src attribute of the referenced element?

Comment: nop, I'm a total newbie in React, don't know ref !

Comment: If you provide the code for the component that this code occurs in, I can show you an example of how to do it

Comment: I added the code at the end of the question, is it the code you need ?

Comment: Yes, that's good, but actually have you tried just appending it directly (look at my answer)

Comment: Also, what's the error you get if you try providing the path directly in the src?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing this: `<iframe src={pdf + '#toolbar=0'} width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>`

Comment: nice and simple ! Thanks !